# biber inputenc error

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, input-encodings

I'm having a strange error with biblatex using biber as a backengine. My minimal example is:

```
\documentclass {scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{⁨lib.bib}
\begin{document}
asdf  \cite{heupel_international_2018}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the correstponding bibfile is:

```
@article{heupel_international_2018,
  langid = {english},
  title = {International Organisations and Human Rights: {{What}} 
Direct Authority Needs for Its Legitimation},
  volume = {44},
  issn = {0260-2105, 1469-9044},
  url = {https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/review-of- 
 international-studies/article/international-organisations-and-human- 
 rights-what-direct-authority-needs-for-its- 
 legitimation/5C605ECBAA1E2667D07BBFB3EACDA3CA},
  doi = {10.1017/S0260210517000420},
  shorttitle = {International Organisations and Human Rights},
 number = {2},
  journaltitle = {Review of International Studies},
  urldate = {2018-08-12},
  date = {2018-04},
  pages = {343-366},
  keywords = {Legitimacy,International Organizations,Authority,Human 
Rights,Legitimation},
  author = {Heupel, Monika and Hirschmann, Gisela and Z\"urn, Michael},   
}
```

I gives me the error: 
"INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '\GenericError {(inputenc)                }{Package inputenc Error: Unicode character \GenericError {(inputenc)                }{Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ⁨ (U+2068)\MessageBreak not set up for use with LaTeX}"

Comment: @moewe that's odd as there is a U+2068 (FIRST STRONG ISOLATE) character in the posted code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Makes sense, I always replace the `\addbibresource` with a `filecontents`-generated `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}`. And I really didn't expect the problem to come from the document ...

Comment: @moewe I pasted the OPs code into https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html :-)

Comment: Note that the line breaks in the URL field will be encoded as spaces, you should remove them. The `issn` field should only hold one ISSN (just like `isbn`, `doi` and `url` only hold one item). I'd also write `Zürn` instead of `Z\"urn`. `german` will give you *alte Rechtschreibung*, if you want *neue Rechtschreibung* you need `ngerman`.

Comment: Instead of `title = {International Organisations and Human Rights: {{What}} 
Direct Authority Needs for Its Legitimation},` and `shorttitle = {International Organisations and Human Rights},` I'd go with `title = {International Organisations and Human Rights},`  and `subtitle={What Direct Authority Needs for Its Legitimation},`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought you might have :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a U+2068 control character between the `{` and `l` in

```
\addbibresource{⁨lib.bib}
```

retype that line with just the visible characters, i.e.

```
\addbibresource{lib.bib}
```

Comment: You're right. Deleting the entire line and retyping it worked. Thanks alot!